# Wordpress Pagination show posts on same page not new page

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I am just finishing off a custom wordpress theme, and was wanting to make a change to the way Pagination works in the index.php file. Currently when I click the pagination links it will take me to a new page, to display the other posts (assuming I have set in the settings for it to display less than the total number of posts). This is fine, however ideally I would like the posts to just pop up at the bottom, underneath the ones already there from the loop.

Currently I am using:

```
    <?php next_posts_link('Older Posts'); ?>
    <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts'); ?>
```

If I haven't explained this well enough let me know and I will try elaborate.

Thank you!

Comment: How about this plugin? https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for an method to load posts via ajax instead of a new page load. I use the [JetPack](https://jetpack.me) Infinite Scroll extension. It should give you what you want but it can be rather difficult to setup for custom templates. Just follow the directions precisely.

Comment: Also, if you don't want to install Jetpack and connect it to your Wordpress.com account (typical if you are doing client work) then use the [Slim Jetpack](https://wordpress.org/plugins/slimjetpack/) plugin. This might be the easier option but works the same way.